# How can I attach onclick event to each item generated from vuejs "v-for=" to show or hide its inner element

Tags: javascript, html, loops, vue.js, vuejs2

My vue data is

```
data: function() { 
    return {
      results: { 
        "items": [
           {
            "id": "770c257b-7ded-437c-99b5-3b8953b5be3a",
            "name": "Gsbssbb",
            "price": 9559,
            "colour": {
                "name": "Blue",
                "hex": "FF0000AE"
            },
            "amountAvailable": 949
        },
        {
            "id": "8ecc6558-0c16-4497-b742-5eb5cb28c572",
            "name": "Vsbdbdb",
            "price": 6559,
            "colour": {
                "name": "Purple",
                "hex": "FF800080"
            },
            "amountAvailable": 6595
        }
    ],
}
```

The template is

```
<div class="column asoebi-list-item" v-for="result in results.items">
                  <div id="item-event" class="columns is-mobile">
                      <div class="column auto has-text-left">
                          <p class="item-name">{{result.name}}</p>
                          <p class="item-price" id="item-price">  {{result.price}}</p>
                          <p class="item-units">{{result.amountAvailable}} Units Remaining &#183; {{result.colour.name}}</p>
                      </div>
                       <div class="column is-2">

                                <button id="number-spinner-up" class="o-button button-bottom"  type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('[type=number]').stepUp();">
                                    +
                                </button>
                                    <input id="count-input" type="number" name="number" min="0" max="900" v-model="count">
                        <button  id="number-spinner-down" class="o-button button-top" type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('[type=number]').stepDown();">
                                    -
                        </button>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

As i loop through each data and display them, How can I add event to hide and un-hide div with number id "number-spinner" class and buttons on each element displayed.

I have this already written, but it only affects the first item even if I click on other items.

```
 let allItems = document.querySelectorAll("#item-event");
        for (let i = 0; i <= allItems.length; i++) { 
            allItems[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                this.toggleSpinner()
                  }); 
                }
```

```
    toggleSpinner: function() {
          let countInput = document.getElementById("count-input");
          countInput.style.visibility = "visible"
          let theElementStyle1 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("number-spinner-up"));
          let theElementStyle2 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("number-spinner-down"));
          if(theElementStyle1.visibility === "hidden") {
              document.getElementById("number-spinner-up").style.visibility = "visible";
          }
          else {
              if(countInput.value === "0") {
                countInput.style.visibility = "hidden"
          }
              document.getElementById("number-spinner-up").style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
          if(theElementStyle2.visibility === "hidden") {
              document.getElementById("number-spinner-down").style.visibility = "visible";
          }
          else {
            if(countInput.value === "0") {
                countInput.style.visibility = "hidden"
          }
              document.getElementById("number-spinner-down").style.visibility = "hidden";
          } 

      },
```

I just started with vue.. please forgive my sloppyness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to keep jQuery away from Vue, since it is having its own functionalities to handle most of the requirements.

I'm not clear which div should set for toggle the view. So I added one link to toggle it. Hope this will help.

```
        <div class="column asoebi-list-item" v-for="result in results.items">
            <div id="item-event" class="columns is-mobile">
                <div class="column auto has-text-left">
                    <p class="item-name">{{result.name}}</p>
                    <p class="item-price" id="item-price"> {{result.price}}</p>
                    <p class="item-units">{{result.amountAvailable}} Units Remaining &#183; {{result.colour.name}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-2" v-show="result.active">
                    <button id="number-spinner-up" class="o-button button-bottom" type="button"
                            onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('[type=number]').stepUp();">
                        +
                    </button>
                    <input id="count-input" type="number" name="number" min="0" max="900" v-model="result.count">
                    <button id="number-spinner-down" class="o-button button-top" type="button"
                            onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('[type=number]').stepDown();">
                        -
                    </button>
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="result.active=!result.active">toggle</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also, made some changes to the array `results` to handle the `v-model` and toggle functionality

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            results: {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "770c257b-7ded-437c-99b5-3b8953b5be3a",
                        "name": "Gsbssbb",
                        "price": 9559,
                        "colour": {
                            "name": "Blue",
                            "hex": "FF0000AE"
                        },
                        "amountAvailable": 949,
                        "count": null,
                        "active": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "8ecc6558-0c16-4497-b742-5eb5cb28c572",
                        "name": "Vsbdbdb",
                        "price": 6559,
                        "colour": {
                            "name": "Purple",
                            "hex": "FF800080"
                        },
                        "amountAvailable": 6595,
                        "count": null,
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Vue ! Do Not Focus On Operating The DOM !  You are not using jQuery ! Read Vue DOCs before coding !